# Hive GUDF custom unzip function test case failing with error "B cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable"

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm writing test case for Generic UDF custom unzip evaluate function which does unzipping of zip files. This jar is used in Hivequery.
Here code for test case,

```
public void testEvaluate() throws HiveException, IOException {
    Unzip unzip = new Unzip();
    File resourcesDirectory = new File("src/test/resources/test.zip");
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes( resourcesDirectory.toPath() );

    ObjectInspector binaryOI = PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.writableBinaryObjectInspector;
    ObjectInspector[] arguments = {binaryOI};
    unzip.initialize(arguments);

    GenericUDF.DeferredObject valueObj0 = new GenericUDF.DeferredJavaObject(bytes);
    GenericUDF.DeferredObject[] args = { valueObj0 };

    unzip.evaluate(args  );}
```

**I'm getting error as below**,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable

at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableBinaryObjectInspector.getPrimitiveJavaObject(WritableBinaryObjectInspector.java:49)
at Unzip.evaluate(Unzip.java:32)
at UnzipTest.testEvaluate(UnzipTest.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

**The error is occuring at line when reading bytes from DeferredObject[] args,**

```
 -  byte[] input = elementOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject( arg[0].get() );
```

PS: test.zip contains a text file(with test string) zipped to test.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to wrap `byte[]` with a Writable that Hive can work with, `BytesWritable` in your case.
As you can see [`WritableBinaryObjectInspector.getPrimitiveJavaObject` expects `BytesWritable` object as an input, not an array of bytes.](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/4446414f4478091db1eb20bc782a5c1825356153/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/objectinspector/primitive/WritableBinaryObjectInspector.java#L49)

Try instead of

```java
GenericUDF.DeferredObject valueObj0 = new GenericUDF.DeferredJavaObject(bytes);
```

do the following:

```java
GenericUDF.DeferredObject valueObj0 = new GenericUDF.DeferredJavaObject(new BytesWritable(bytes));
```

Reproducing your case locally I was able to retrieve `byte[]` inside UDF `evaluate` method successfully.

Comment: Thank you, it worked after converting to bytes writable.I figured it out later.